# Please I need interpretation of the visa denial letter from the French consulate

Tags: student-visa

I want to reapply for a student visa in France, but I do not understand why the first visa was denied. The rejection letter states that "you have not submitted sufficient evidence allowing the consular authority to insure in France that purpose of study will not be abusive".
What does this mean?

[image]

> Vous n'avez pas présenté d'éléments suffisants permettant à l'autorité consulaire de s'assurer en France á des fins d'études ne présenterait pas un caractère abusif

Google translation:

> You have not submitted sufficient evidence allowing the consular authority to insure in France for study purposes would not be abusive

Comment: Please do not use pictures of text on SE sites - these are not searchable. I have edited your question.

Comment: Following on from Jan's (correct) comment, the (redacted) copy of the rejection letter itself is very helpful though.

Answer (score 5):

This means that the French consulate doesn’t think that you are or will be a genuine student. This could be caused by a number of factors:

- your school is one that has a reputation for attracting “students” who don’t end up studying
- your finances don’t seem sufficient for your course of study and you might end up working under the table
- you seem for a number of factors (which sadly can include your country's economic state) unlikely to return after your course of study

As far as reapplying, if you apply without changing any of the above, you'll get refused again. You should think about:

- applying to a better quality school
- improving your finances or evidence of finances
- showing why you have reason to return to your home country after you go to school